# Контент меню по всей ширине страницы

Tags: html, css

Нужно, чтобы блок с зеленой обводкой был по всей ширине страницы (нужно чтобы именно цвет фона был по всей ширине), а сам контент был в соответствии с шириной контейнера). Сложность в том, что должна сохраниться вложенность данного блока, т.к в дальнейшем будет адаптивность

```css
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {
  background: #ccc;
}

.navbar-inner {
  height: 60px;
}

.menu {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}

.menu__item {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100%/8);
  text-align: center;
}
.menu__item:hover {
  background: #7f8fa6;
}

.menu__link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #95afc0;
  border: 3px dashed green;
}

.submenu-content {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Журчит несколько свой, дорогу взгляд осталось на берегу встретил текста повстречался текстов! За, силуэт сбить? Толку, жаренные рыбными. Имеет, но жизни?</p>
</div>
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">item V</a>
        <div class="submenu">
          <div class="submenu-content">
            <p>Это Подменю</p>
            <p>с Шириной как у контейнера</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">item</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">item        </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Пробовал сделать со 100% width, но как подобрать padding чтобы было как в контейнере и адаптивно?

Comment: я не увидел обнуление дефолтных стилей - где они ?

Comment: вот Вы к примеру нормалайзе когда подключили ваш серый фон стал на 100% экрана

Comment: так и нужно. Осталось сделать по всей ширине блок с зеленой обводкой, но оставить контент по ширине контейнера

Comment: Не совсем, к сожалению. 
Может так будет немного понятнее:
http://prntscr.com/l7fgqq

Comment: я переделал - посмотри опять ссылку [codepen](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/MPVooy?editors=1000)

Comment: Моя ошибка, что не подробно описал, нужно сохранять вложенность в li, это нужно будет для адаптива. На мобильных это будет меню-аккордеон

Comment: тогда это не возможно ...а адаптивность можно сделать в любом варианте

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {
  background: #ccc;
}

.navbar-inner {
  height: 60px;
}

.menu {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}

.menu__item {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100%/8);
  text-align: center;
}
.menu__item:hover {
  background: #7f8fa6;
}

.menu__link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 3px dashed green;
}

.submenu:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  background: #95afc0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.submenu-content {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Журчит несколько свой, дорогу взгляд осталось на берегу встретил текста повстречался текстов! За, силуэт сбить? Толку, жаренные рыбными. Имеет, но жизни?</p>
</div>
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">item V</a>
        <div class="submenu">
          <div class="submenu-content">
            <p>Это Подменю</p>
            <p>с Шириной как у контейнера</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">item</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Можно использовать :before